# Eager Load Dynamic Attribute in Laravel for jQuery Datatable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, datatable, datatables

I have a `Hotel` Model, which `hasMany` `Guests`, which in turn has two dynamic attributes as follows.

```
public function getNameAttribute(){
     return $this->user->name;
}

public function getEmailAttribute(){
    return $this->user->email;
}
```

Now I prefer to fetch them as `$hotel->guests()->with('user')`. Now when I use it for Datatable, I am not able to get the name & email in the view, for obvious reasons. So my question is, Can I eager-load the name & email attributes, so that whenever the guest model gets fetched, the said attributes are available.

Please note, I don't return it `asArray` or `asJson`, hence the concept of `$attributes` array doesn't apply (at-least as far as I know).

The Controller has the following code:

```
return Datatables::of($guests)
            ->addColumn('email',function($guest){
                return $guest->email;
            })
            ->addColumn('name',function($guest){
                return $guest->name;
            })->make(true);
```

However, the datatable cannot search for name or email because they are not available in database.

The jquery datatable code I use is

```
$(function() {
$('#guest-table').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: '{!! route('guests.data') !!}',
    columns: [
        { data: 'name', name: 'name', orderable: false },
        { data: 'email', name: 'email', orderable: false},
        { data: 'mobile', name: 'mobile', orderable: false}
    ]
   });
});
```

I use `Laravel 5` and `yajra/laravel-datatables` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per the Yajra, Laravel document, you have to call the property of the related model in this way,

```
{data: 'relation_name.column', name: 'relationName.column'}
```

so in your case it will be like this,

```
{data: 'user.name', name: 'user.name'}
{data: 'user.email', name: 'user.email'}
```

Answer (score 0):

User double quotes here, I will work if this code is inside blade file

```
 ajax: "{!! route('guests.data') !!}",
```

If you have external js file then use like this

Create a hidden field in blade file

```
 <input type="hidden" id="route_url" value="{!! route('guests.data') !!}">
```

And in js file take route url by id

```
ajax: $("#route_url").val(),
```